# how to authenticate using username password with django and django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Good day, I'm not sure of being wrong or right. I've an django which authenticate the user with password and email, I override the form forthis case as shown in the django tutorial.
However, I do have a part in which I'd like to integrate the rest framework, and which will require the user to be logged in with the same username and password in order to view the api in the browser. Is it feasible to use the same credentials on both authentication method ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes- did you include the URLs for the Django REST Framework browsable API when you followed the install guide? From the install [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation):

*If you're intending to use the browsable API you'll probably also want to add REST framework's login and logout views. Add the following to your root urls.py file.*

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

If you followed all the steps:

*You can now open the API in your browser at http://127.0.0.1:8000/, and view your new 'users' API. If you use the login control in the top right corner you'll also be able to add, create and delete users from the system.*

Try navigating to the root of your API- assuming you have the UserViewset defined from the install, this would be something like `/api/` and you should see `users` in the list.